# How do i run this servelet code in ubuntu from terminal

Tags: java, jsp, ubuntu-14.04

I have Tomcat7 up and running.It has passed all the basic necessary tests.Now i have written a simple servlet code in a folder A.The code is as follows:

```
 package testPackage;
 import javax.servlet.*;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;
 import java.io.*;
 @WebServlet("/hello") 
 public class HelloworldServelet extends HttpServlet
 {
 @Override
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse rep)throws IOException,ServletException
 {
    rep.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=rep.getWriter();    
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
}
```

Now i can't run it.No way can it to display it in the browser.What are the methods of displaying it using terminal.I am not using any IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, everyone has to begin.

A servlet runs in a Java EE (=extra classes like HttpServletRequest) web container like Tomcat which runs `.war` files, web applications.

Maybe you even did not compile the .java code.

In this case you'll be better of starting with a simple [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm), and start from there.

Comment: I have tried to compile it but it keeps giving an error that package javax.servlet not present.

Comment: That is because of the Java EE classes being an extra layer. There is Java SE (Standard Edition) which goes with the JDK. Beside that there are the Java EE (Enterprise Edition) classes, also free to download. Best to use an IDE like NetBeans, install or insure it has Java EE support, and create a web project. I mention NetBeans becaus e one can download a version with JavaEE + a web server (Glassfish, Tomcat).